# Exporting BigQuery table to GCS using gcloud-python

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

The example here is outdated https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html#exporting-data-async. The example gives error: AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'export_to_storage'

How do I construct and run a job extracting BigQuery table to Google Cloud Storage in CSV/JSON format in gcloud-python v.0.8.0?

Thanks

Comment: I did 'git rev-list --all | xargs git grep export_to_storage' on the project which shows the code for 'export_to_storage' never existed - it's only ever referenced in the documentation. I don't see this mentioned on the issues page either. It's a good case for opening a documentation issue using the 'Report an issue' link on the page.

Comment: Issue reported: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/issues/1397